# How to get details of Spring Boot @Async method's rejected task?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

In my application I'm using an `@Async` method which is calling a rest service and based on the rest service result I'm updating the MyJob status in DB.

```
@Async("thatOneTaskExecutor")
public void myAsyncTask(MyJob job) {
    // get job details from the job and call rest service
    // update the job with the result from rest service and save updated MyJob to DB
}
```

I'm using Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExucutor`, Below is a snap from my `AsyncConfiguration` class where I declared this task executor.

```
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor createExecutor(String name, int core, int max, int queue) {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(core);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(max);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(queue);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(name);
        executor.setTaskDecorator(new MdcAwareTaskDecorator());
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

@Bean(name = "thatOneTaskExecutor")
public Executor taskExecutor() {

    String prefix = "thatOneTask-";
    String corePoolSize = 12;
    String maxPoolSize = 20;
    String queueSize = 1000;

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = createExecutor(prefix, corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, queueSize);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl());
    return executor;
}
```

As you can see I had configured a `RejectedExecutionHandler` for my Executor.
According to Spring documentation when ***queue*** is full this method will be called.

> ```
>  * Method that may be invoked by a {@link ThreadPoolExecutor} when
>  * {@link ThreadPoolExecutor#execute execute} cannot accept a
>  * task.  This may occur when no more threads or queue slots are
>  * available because their bounds would be exceeded, or upon
>  * shutdown of the Executor.
> ```

```
public class RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        log.error("Task Rejected because of max queue size");
        // How to get info about that particular job, for which Task executor rejected this task??
    } 
}
```

Rejected execution handler is working fine for me, now inside this `rejectedExecutorion` method, I want to access the **MyJob**(parameter of my async method) for which the async task is rejected. I want to update that particular rejected job with a status so that I can later run a corn and process those rejected jobs. Inside this `rejectedExecution` method I only have `Runnable` and `ThreadPoolExucutor`, how can I extract/get info about MyJob here?

My application's Spring boot version is **2.2.2.RELEASE**

Comment: One thing, can we use something like observer? Set an observer and observe it inside `rejectedExecution` ?

Comment: But how that observer will get information about the `MyJob`? You see the problem here is I to want access the param of the @async method for which is rejectedMethod is called.

Comment: Looks like the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is bit constrained in this case: it is not passing sufficient context (`MyJob` in your case) to the callback for handling rejections (`rejectedExecution` in your case). If the API is not helping, you don't have much to do other than seeking some alternative.

Comment: Not sure if it's going to work, however, you may try setting a [decorator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setTaskDecorator-org.springframework.core.task.TaskDecorator-) around the task invocation. Wrap the actual invocation of the `Runnable` in try-catch, catch the exception thrown by the executor (supposed to be `RejectedExecutionException`), check (by debugging probably) if the exception gives you necessary context, and implement error handling there.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using the `TaskExecutor` directly instead of the `@Async` annotation by implementing the `Runnable` interface for `MyJob` Class and perform the required async operation inside the `run()` method.

The `Runnable r` could be cast back to `MyJob` Object in the `rejectedExecution` method of the handler and hence you could retrieve information of your job from there.

```
 public class Myjob implements Runnable{
   .......
   @Override
   public void run(){
         //get job details from the job and call rest service
         //update the job with the result from rest service and save updated MyJob to DB
      }
 }
```

---

```
@Autowired
TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
 
public void myAsyncTask(MyJob job) {
   taskExecutor.execute(job)
}
```

---

```
public class RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        log.error("Task Rejected because of max queue size");
        if(r.getClass()==MyJob.class)
         {
            MyJob failedJob=(MyJob)r; //Job info
         }

    } 
 }
```

---